# Cannot freeze devtool chrome with F8

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I would like to know the code source behind the choice "Custom" :

[image]

But when I press F8 to freeze the website, it doesn't work, it just delete my action :

[image]

And if I press F8 again it work but there is no code source to inspect anymore :

[image]

I don't understand why it doesn't work anymore. I already managed to do it several weeks ago but now it doesn't work.

It seems that F8 reset the arrow (she goes black to white), that's strange. Because when the arrow is white, F8 work.

Comment: Is the url a public url? Can you share?

Comment: It's not, you need ID and I cannot give them sorry